# In ASP.NET MVC, how to make a dropdown for a related entity, instead of a foreign key property?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-binding, drop-down-menu

Let's say I have this model:

```
public class Category {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Item {
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //public long CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

I want to edit an item on my page, I have a list of categories.

I could easily create a dropdown for the CategoryId property. But I need to have the entire Category entity mapped instead of just a foreign key. Is there a conventional, generic way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because you cannot set the `value` attribute of an option to an entire entity, let alone post that back in a format that the modelbinder could recognize. The proper way to handle this is that you post to the foreign key property and then save.

If your problem is that you do not have a foreign key property (because you've relied on EF conventions to create it for you based on the `Category` property), then your best bet is to utilize a view model in your view instead of the actual entity. In that view model, you can include the `CategoryId` property and use that for your dropdown. Then, once you receive the model back in your POST action, you use the id to query the database and retrieve the actual object. You then set `Category` on your entity to this object and save.